# What are <none> repository and tags? Why do they appear when I use docker build?

Tags: docker

This is what `docker images` shows before I run `docker build`.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
myapp               latest              a38da0bd9e0b        6 seconds ago       523.8 MB
golang              onbuild             b4997c557048        10 days ago         517.2 MB
```

After I make some changes to the `myapp` source code, I run `docker build -t myapp .` and I end up with images named `<none>`.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED                      VIRTUAL SIZE
myapp               latest              a38da0bd9e0b        Less than a second ago ago   523.8 MB
<none>              <none>              e4209f97e819        10 minutes ago               523.8 MB
golang              onbuild             b4997c557048        10 days ago                  517.2 MB
```

I know I can remove them with `docker rmi <IMAGE ID>`, but why does that happen in the first place? How can I prevent that from happening? The `Dockerfile` I'm building looks like this.

```
FROM golang:onbuild
EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you reassign a tag or image name to another image, your image will lose its tag or name. It's really that simple. Your `myapp` repo image tagged `latest` with ID `a38da0bd9e0b` used to be named and tagged on image ID `e4209f97e819`.

Comment: You can do something like `docker tag e4209f97e819 myName/myApp:latest` and it will be tagged, but keep in mind that you can untag another image if it has the same tag. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#setting-tags-on-an-image) is more information about tagging. Good luck!

Comment: It seems as though this <none> problem also occurs when you try to name your image with something containing a capital letter. For example I built an image with docker build -t myname/NewImage:0.1 . and this resulted in my image having a repo and tag of <none>.

Comment: You built an image with `docker build -t myname/NewImage:0.1 .` more than one time. The first time you do this, it creates an image tagged with `myname/NewImage:0.1`. The second time you do this, it creates a *new* image which gets the `myname/NewImage:0.1` tag, leaving the *first* image you built having tags of `<none>`.

Comment: And to remove these images you need to remove the latest image with correct repo and tag. Is that right ?

Comment: Is there a way to automatically remove previously created images after rebuilding with a fresh one?

Comment: @kxc Do you mean after rebuilding with a fresh image but with the same name? Or a different name?

Comment: @need_to_know_now yeap - with the same name. So after each rebuilding, there wouldn't be a new image in the list but just the old name will be replaced with a new image

Comment: @kxc I don't think there is a way to do that, as that seems to be an intrinsic feature of Docker. Although, my experience with Docker isn't that expansive, so you should still try to look further. You could always run "docker system prune" or "docker container prune" to remove any dangling containers.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the times what I have observed is, this happens when we don't provide a tag name while building an image
so if we run only `docker build .` , it vl create image with `<none>` as showed below:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
<none>       <none>    2c37709c9ce7   About an hour ago   157MB
<none>       <none>    9dd3b14c6c97   About an hour ago   497MB
```

Another reason is, these could be intermediate images,
these images are called ***dangling images*** and can be removed with below command (if not running currently)

```
docker images prune
```

And if it's genuine image, just ran without -t by mistake, we can tag it later as well as with below command:

```
docker tag <ImageID> my-app:latest
```

I hope this will answer some other questions as well, along with the asked one

Comment: Liked that prune command but should be "docker image prune" The extra S makes it list an image named "prune"

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting up the tag right in the build command. Try:

`docker build -t repo/stuff:tag .`

This will work if your Dockerfile is named "Dockerfile" and you're in the directory you want to build from.

When you run `docker image list` it'll show `repo/stuff` as the repository and `tag` as the TAG