# docker images output manipulation

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to delete each docker image that it's `name == none` in my system.

I have tried this

```
for image in $(docker images  | grep none); do echo $image; done
```

But this gives me the output of each column like that:

```
<none>      
<none>      
a20d00ca4041
19          
minutes     
ago         
227MB
```

I want it like that:

```
<none>            <none>              a20d00ca4041        20 minutes ago      227MB
```

So i can delete delete the image by it's id.

Any help ?

Comment: If you want to remove the *"dangling"* images you can do it with: `docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`. More here: [Why the “none” image appears in Docker and how can we avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53221412/why-the-none-image-appears-in-docker-and-how-can-we-avoid-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use awk command instead

```
docker images | grep "none" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on dov answer this make more sense to me:

EDIT:
As Mark suggested this is shorter and cleaner.

```
docker rmi $(docker images | awk ' /none/ {print $3}')
```

Comment: `grep + awk` is something of an antipattern. Forget `grep` and just use `awk '/none/ {print $3}'`

Comment: @Mark You are right I didn't know about this option, thank you.