# How to remove all prior builds, containers, repositories, and tags on Docker build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my current docker / docker-compose workflow:

- Make some code changes
- `sudo docker build --rm . -t image_name`
- Ctrl + C `docker-compose` process
- `sudo docker-compose down`
- `sudo docker-compose up`

Why then, when I run [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) does the space deleted increase in proportion with the number of times I run through this process? Using `sudo docker build --rm . -t image_name`:

```
deleted: sha256: blablablah
deleted: sha256: ... 
deleted: sha256: blablablah

Total reclaimed space: 1.948GB // Roughly proportional to the number of build runs
```

I was under the impression that `sudo docker build --rm . -t image_name`, using [--rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/), would remove any intermediary images and containers.  Or is it just images that get automatically deleted, while past containers persist? If so, is there a way to clean up past containers and images on each Docker build without having to remember to occasionally run docker system prune? Should I set up a job to automate this in development?

**EDIT**: I do not think my question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179716/what-are-none-repository-and-tags-why-do-they-appear-when-i-use-docker-build). When I run `sudo docker images`, there are no `<none>` containers. Therefore, the question is not a duplicate of the question, "*What are `<none>` repository and tags? Why do they appear when I use docker build?*" However, it does appear a clue to the answer to my question appears to be in the comments:

> You built an image with docker build -t myname/NewImage:0.1 . more
>   than one time. The first time you do this, it creates an image tagged
>   with myname/NewImage:0.1. The second time you do this, it creates a
>   new image which gets the myname/NewImage:0.1 tag, leaving the first
>   image you built having tags of `<none>`

This comment is accurate, but I do not appear to have any `<none>` containers. Further, even with this comment, my follow up question of how to avoid this is unanswered:

- ***"...is there a way to clean up past containers and images on each
  Docker build without having to remember to occasionally run docker
  system prune? "***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are <none> repository and tags? Why do they appear when I use docker build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179716/what-are-none-repository-and-tags-why-do-they-appear-when-i-use-docker-build)

Comment: If you run `docker images` after each build you’ll see the previous build left behind as a `<none>` image, and that’s what the prune command is cleaning up.  `--rm=false` will keep the containers created by each `RUN` step; `--rm=true` is the default; this option doesn’t affect a previous image with the same tag.