# Docker keeping different images and containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working with dockerized applications and docker-compose.

So sometimes I just run `docker-compose up` and other times run a particular service `docker-compose run service1 /bin/bash`

I'm noticing it's increasing a lot of different images and containers using it that way.

For example:

```
docker images -a
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                    <none>              7579570fc0f6        3 minutes ago       2.07GB
<none>                    <none>              5c4dff8b6808        8 minutes ago       1.34GB
<none>                    <none>              abf3cb89f2fa        9 minutes ago       1.34GB
<none>                    <none>              7592dcccab3b        9 minutes ago       1.27GB
<none>                    <none>              da2be213241c        9 minutes ago       1.27GB
<none>                    <none>              52bbbc8b88c8        4 weeks ago         1.96GB
<none>                    <none>              77a6403fe043        4 weeks ago         1.96GB
<none>                    <none>              4845935c3110        4 weeks ago         1.23GB
<none>                    <none>              48bca82f00c9        4 weeks ago         1.23GB
<none>                    <none>              63d77ddad079        4 weeks ago         1.94GB
<none>                    <none>              6729473d9848        4 weeks ago         1.94GB
<none>                    <none>              e6ef1c44689f        4 weeks ago         1.23GB
```

And it's similar with `docker container ls -a`

It doesn't feel right, am I missing some good practice here? Should I add something to the docker-compose.yml to prevent this?

Update:
Have seen the comments about handling dangling images and , but my question here is actually how to prevent this.
For example, I know there's a way to run images with a remove tag to destroy it after stop, is it a good practice? I don't see it in the guides so I'm not using, however, the current scenario is making me worried about disk space...

Comment: I've written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53224187/1561148) about `dangling` and `intermediate` images which might help.

Comment: @tgogos is this still the best way to remove dangling images? I've since been using `docker system prune` which works a treat.

Comment: @MattB. I think both are OK. You can read what 2 docker captains (Nick Janetakis & Adrian Mouat) discuss about this issue here: [How to Remove Dangling Docker Images](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-31-how-to-remove-dangling-docker-images)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are <none> repository and tags? Why do they appear when I use docker build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179716/what-are-none-repository-and-tags-why-do-they-appear-when-i-use-docker-build)

Comment: One simple answer here is to just not run `docker images -a`: it prints out a line for each _layer_ and that’s rarely interesting information, `docker rmi` will clean up intermediate layers if that’s appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Typically `docker-compose up`. Use `up` to start or restart all the services defined in a `docker-compose.yml`. In the default “attached” mode, you see all the logs from all the containers. In “detached” mode (`-d`), Compose exits after starting the containers, but the containers continue to run in the background.

The `docker-compose run` command is for running “one-off” or “adhoc” tasks. It requires the service name you want to run and only starts containers for services that the running service depends on. Use run to run tests or perform an administrative task such as removing or adding data to a data volume container. The `run` command acts like `docker run -ti` in that it opens an interactive terminal to the container and returns an exit status matching the exit status of the process in the container.